# Scheme Help - File Statistics

Tags: file-io, scheme

So I have to finish a project in Scheme and I'm pretty stuck. Basically, what the program does is open a file and output the statistics. Right now I am able to count the number of characters, but I also need to count the number of lines and words. I'm just trying to tackle this situation for now but eventually I also have to take in two files - the first being a text file, like a book. The second will be a list of words, I have to count how many times those words appear in the first file. Obviously I'll have to work with lists but I would love some help on where to being. Here is the code that I have so far (and works)

```
(define filestats
          (lambda (srcf wordcount linecount charcount )

                (if (eof-object? (peek-char srcf ) )
                    (begin
                        (close-port srcf)
                        (display linecount)
                        (display " ")
                        (display wordcount)
                        (display " ")
                        (display charcount)
                        (newline) ()
                    )
                    (begin
                        (read-char srcf)
                        (filestats srcf  0 0 (+ charcount 1))   
                    )
                )

            )
)

(define filestatistics
  (lambda (src)
    (let ((file (open-input-file src)))
       (filestats file 0 0 0)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Stats in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063788/file-stats-in-scheme)

Comment: No 'hanging parens' please; they are not braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about 'tokenizing' the file into a list of lines, where a line is a list of words, and a word is a list of characters.

```
(define (tokenize file)
  (with-input-from-file file
    (lambda ()
      (let reading ((lines '()) (words '()) (chars '()))
        (let ((char (read-char)))
          (if (eof-object? char)
              (reverse lines)
              (case char
                ((#\newline) (reading (cons (reverse (cons (reverse chars) words)) lines) '() '()))
                ((#\space)   (reading lines (cons (reverse chars) words) '()))
                (else        (reading lines words (cons char chars))))))))))
```

once you've done this, the rest is trivial.

```
> (tokenize "foo.data")
(((#\a #\b #\c) (#\d #\e #\f))
 ((#\1 #\2 #\3) (#\x #\y #\z)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The word count algorithm using Scheme has been explained before in Stack Overflow, for example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10060603/201359) (scroll up to the top of the page to see an equivalent program in C):

```
(define (word-count input-port)
  (let loop ((c (read-char input-port))
             (nl 0)
             (nw 0)
             (nc 0)
             (state 'out))
    (cond ((eof-object? c)
           (printf "nl: ~s, nw: ~s, nc: ~s\n" nl nw nc))
          ((char=? c #\newline)
           (loop (read-char input-port) (add1 nl) nw (add1 nc) 'out))
          ((char-whitespace? c)
           (loop (read-char input-port) nl nw (add1 nc) 'out))
          ((eq? state 'out)
           (loop (read-char input-port) nl (add1 nw) (add1 nc) 'in))
          (else
           (loop (read-char input-port) nl nw (add1 nc) state)))))
```

The procedure receives an input port as a parameter, so it's possible to apply it to, say, a file. Notice that for counting words and lines you'll need to test if the current char is either a new line character or a white space character. And an extra flag (called `state` in the code) is needed for keeping track of the start/end of a new word.